# How to delete and add an element from an array based of the user input in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays

```
String[] courseNames=new String[numbOfCourses]; 
Double[] courseCredits=new Double[numbOfCourses];
String[] gradeLetters= new String[numbOfCourses];
```

I asked the user to enter some course names,credits and letters and I put them in each array like:

```
courseNames[j]= keyboard.next();
courseCredits[j]=keyboard.nextDouble();
gradeLetters[j]=keyboard.next();
```

I expect the output to be like

Before:

```
course numb     course name      course credit   course Grade
1                    C               3.0              A
2                    B               3.0              B
3                    D               3.0              A
```

user input: 2

After:

```
course numb     course name      course credit   course Grade
1                    C               3.0              A
2                    D               3.0              A
```

Comment: Do you need to use arrays? You can't really "delete" an element from an array without making a copy of it or shifting all the previous elements following it down and keeping track of the valid size. It would be better to use a `List` instead.

Comment: Don't use arrays if you want to add and/or remove items. Use a `List`. --- Don't use parallel arrays. Java is an **Object-Oriented** language. Use it!! Create a class (e.g. named `Course`) with the 3 properties (e.g. named `name`, `credit`, and `grade`), then have a `List<Course>`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I strongly encourage you to use some kind of List since it will be much easier to achieve your desired effect.

To "delete" an item from the array you could create a method similar to this:

```
void deleteCourseAtIndex(int index) {
    courseNames[index]= null;
    courseCredits[index]= null;
    gradeLetters[index]= null;
}
```

And then when you are doing your printf()'s to display the content of the arrays:

```
for (int i = 0; i < courseNames.length; i++) {
    if (courseNames[i] != null)
        //printf() with whatever formatting you have
}
```

To add a new course, you would have to have enough indices in your arrays to store a new course. This is why I would advise you to use a List. Nonetheless:

```
//This method adds course info to the arrays and returns a boolean whether it was successfully added
//Precondition: all arrays are the same length
boolean addCourse(String[] cNames, double[] cCredits, String[] gLetters) {
    boolean added = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < courseNames.length; i++) {
        if (courseNames[i] == null) {
            courseNames[i]= cNames;
            courseCredits[i]= cCredits;
            gradeLetters[i]= gLetters;
            added = true;
        }
    }
    return added;
}
```

With a List, you don't have to deal with the issue of running out of space because they don't have a fixed size when you initialize them. To do this with Lists, try something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> courseNames= new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<Double> courseCredits = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<String> gradeLetters = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Note that I used Double instead of double because double is a primitive and ArrayLists can't use primitives. Use the wrapper classes Integer, Double etc. when using Lists.

Now when you accept keyboard input:

```
courseNames.add(keyboard.next());
courseCredits.add(keyboard.nextDouble());
gradeLetters.add(keyboard.next());
```

And you don't even need to loop through each index!

Even better, you could make a completely new class called Course (as Andreas suggested) and make an ArrayList.